# How to dynamically move UI elements (mostly mainPanel's) in R shiny?

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

I currently have my UI set up like the picture with a couple of `selectInputs` at the top. I have two questions here:

1) How can I make the "graph panels" that appear at the bottom dependent on the "Selected metrics" input on top. I can't seem to work out how to use a `conditionalPanel` with lists, i.e., how to display multiple panels if multiple inputs are selected. The end result would be the picture below but at the moment there `selectInput` on top does nothing.

2) Is it possible to dynamically move the panels based on what inputs are selected? For example, in the picture below, if I deselect "Drug overdose rate", can I get the "Arthritis prevalence" chart to dynamically move into the overdose rate location? Ironically, the `fluidRow` structure isn't too fluid in this case.

My code for this chunk is as follows (apologies for the commented out code at points):

```
fluidPage(
                  mainPanel(id = "hscontrols", class = "panel panel-default",
                            fluidRow(
                              column(3,
                                     selectInput("healthstates","States:", c(structure(state.abb, names=state.name), "Washington, DC"="DC"),
                                                 selected = "AL",
                                                 multiple = FALSE)
                              ),

                              column(6,
                                     selectInput("hsmetrics", "Selected metrics", 
                                                 c("Drug overdose rate",
                                                   "Arthritis prevalence",
                                                   "Opioid prescribing rate"),
                                                 selected = c("Drug overdose rate",
                                                              "Arthritis prevalence",
                                                              "Opioid prescribing rate"),
                                                 multiple = T))
                            )
                  ),

                  fluidRow(
                    column(4,

                           mainPanel(id = "healthranks", class = "panel panel-default",

                                     h3("Overall health snapshot:"),

                                     # h4(htmlOutput("hsstate")),

                                     dataTableOutput("ranktable1")

                                     # dataTableOutput("ranktable2")

                                     # htmlOutput("healthrankings")
                           )
                    ),

                    column(8,

                           mainPanel(id = "drugoverdose", class = "panel panel-default",

                                     h3("Drug overdose rate:"),

                                     actionButton("drugodtoggle", "Additional info"),
                                     conditionalPanel("input.drugodtoggle % 2 == 0",
                                                      htmlOutput('hsdrugoddef')),

                                     # HTML('<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#drugoddef">Additional info</button>'),
                                     # tags$div(id = 'drugoddef',  class="collapse",
                                     #          htmlOutput('hsdrugoddef')),

                                     plotOutput("drugodplot", hover = hoverOpts(id = "drugod_hover"))
                           )
                    )
                  ),


                  fluidRow(
                    column(6,
                           # conditionalPanel("'Arthritis prevalence' %in% input.hsmetrics",
                           mainPanel(id = "arthritis", class = "panel panel-default",

                                     h3("Arthritis prevalence:"),

                                     actionButton("arthtoggle", "Additional info"),
                                     conditionalPanel("input.arthtoggle % 2 == 0",
                                                      htmlOutput('hsarthdef')),

                                     # HTML('<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#arthdef">Additional info</button>'),
                                     # tags$div(id = 'arthdef',  class="collapse",
                                     #          htmlOutput('hsarthdef')),

                                     plotOutput("arthritisplot")
                           )
                           # )
                    ),

                    column(6,
                           mainPanel(id = "prescribe", class = "panel panel-default",

                                     h3("Opioid prescribing rate:"),

                                     actionButton("prescribetoggle", "Additional info"),
                                     conditionalPanel("input.prescribetoggle % 2 == 0",
                                                      htmlOutput('hsprescribedef')),

                                     # HTML('<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#prescribedef">Additional info</button>'),
                                     # tags$div(id = 'prescribedef',  class="collapse",
                                     #          htmlOutput('hsprescribedef')),

                                     plotOutput("prescribeplot")
                           )
                    )
                  )
                )
```

[image: Static shiny UI]